# Strange Integral Calculation With Traditional Form

Tags: integral-equations

I must be doing something wrong.

I define the following integral:
[image]

The code:

```
\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(\(-W\)/2\), \(W/2\)]\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(\(-L\)/2\), \(L/2\)]a[
    x]\ \[DifferentialD]x\ \[DifferentialD]y\)\)
```

...and I get:`W a[x]` as a result ??

It should be:

[image]

since a[x] is a undefined function of x.

EDIT: If I input it using the "Input Form" and not the "traditional form":

```
Integrate[Integrate[a[x], {x, -L/2, L/2}], {y, -H/2, H/2}]
```

Mathematica understands it, and I get the correct result.

**Why is that ?**

EDIT 2: Putting it into parenthesis does not help:

[image]

EDIT 3: Putting the paranthesis around the inner integral, solves the problem, but I don't understand why I have to do that. Mathematica should automatically see that where the integral starts and ends.

[image]

Comment: put the inner integral in parantheses?

Comment: @kglr I tried it. It give the same wrong answer.

Comment: I get the desired result in version 11.3 (windows 10 - 64-bit).

Comment: @kglr Strange, I have the same version and operation system.

Comment: [Integral >> Details and Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html): _Multiple integrals use a variant of the standard iterator notation. The first variable given corresponds to the outermost integral and is done last._

Comment: Compare Integrate[a[x], {x, -L/2, L/2}, {y, -H/2, H/2}] with Integrate[a[x], {y, -H/2, H/2}, {x, -L/2, L/2}].